# Update field in a table on a database 1 from an external identical database 2

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

To keep this shot.

I would like to update a field of product_price with all prices where I keep on an external demo table.

I tried to use the following query but it's throwing error

```
UPDATE dest
SET product_price = src.product_price
FROM DB2.trades AS dest
INNER JOIN DB1.trades AS src
ON dest.KEY = src.KEY
--And KEY = '12323';
```

Could you please help with how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that table you're updating resides in database DB2 and "external" table resides in another database (DB1), you'll need to create a database link to DB1 (let's call it `dbl_db1`) and reference its table as `trades@dbl_db1`. Something like this:

```
update trades d set
  d.product_price = (select s.product_price
                     from trades@dbl_db1 s
                     where s.key = d.key
                    )
where exists (select null from trades@dbl_db1 a
              where a.key = d.key
             );
```

Or, using `MERGE`:

```
merge into trades d
  using trades@dbl_db1 s
  on (s.key = d.key)
  when matched then update set
    d.product_price = s.product_price;
```

Comment: db1  = connection name? or username?

Comment: I took it from your query, you should know. Used that way, it represents "another user in the same database who granted you (at least) SELECT privilege on its table".

Comment: Error starting at line : 1 in command -
merge into trades d
  using Demo_Trade.trades s
  on (s.key = d.key)
  when matched then update set
    d.product_price = s.product_price;
Error at Command Line : 2 Column : 21
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: As it says, current user can't see that table. It appears that it really *is* another database, not user in *this* database. If that's the case, create & use a database link. I updated code I previously wrote; have a look.